# How to hard code the domain of email address for the user name through html?

Tags: html, css

I have designed a login page through html and thinking to hardcode the domain of the email address.

Eg: username:  XXXX@gmail.com

I want to hardcode the "gmail.com" so that users can just key in their name.Please help me in resolving this.

```
<form action="post" class="login-form">
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="user-name">Username:</label>
        <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user"id="user-name">
      </div>
      <div class="form-group">
        <label for="password">Password:</label>
        <input type="password" class="form-control" name="password" id="password">
      </div>
      <div class="button-container text-right">
        <button class="btn btn-default" type="button" id="btn-cancel">Cancel</button>
        <button class="btn btn-primary" type="button" id="btn-login">Login</button>
      </div>
    </form>
```

Comment: you can concatenate '@gmail.com' when the user has posted the form.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. It simply concatenates '@gmail.com' after the user has submitted the form.

```
<?php
If ($_POST){
    $email = $_POST['user'].'@gmail.com';
} ?>
```

and the HTML

REPLACE

```
<input id="user-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="user">
```

BY

```
<input id="user-name" class="form-control" type="text" name="user"> @gmail.com
```

Comment: and after the input tag add the @gmail.com so the user will know that it'll get added.

Comment: <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user-name"> @gmail.com

Comment: Actually, I want to display '@gmail.com' beside the username textbox.Can it be possible?

Comment: Use this. <input type="text" class="form-control" name="user" id="user-name"> @gmail.com

Comment: Yeah got it.Thanks :)

Comment: ofcourse. Post the html portion,will select as answer :)

Comment: Updated my answer :)

Comment: There should be some validation instead of just concatenating @gmail.com at the end..

Comment: That is exactly what I am writing in jquery for him right now :)

Comment: @Rahul, do you have jquery included?

Comment: @Ali : No.                                                                                                                            Btwn, the text "@gmail.com" is displaying below the username textbox. How can I make it display beside the textbox? Here is my css :                          .login-box
{
  display: block;
  border:  solid grey;
  padding: 20px 10px;
  text-align: center;
  
  
}

Comment: Try and deleting form-control class from input field.

Comment: @AliZia , After deleting the 'form-control' class, username and it's text box is displayed in a single line.But, '@gmail.com' is still getting displayed below the username text box and not beside the textbox. Pls lemme know how to resolve this...

Comment: or just give me the link to your site.

Comment: The fiddle seems to be okay at me end. The input field and @gmail.com are in the same line.

Comment: I have replied in chat [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/105090/discussion-between-rahul-and-ali-zia).